# MVC Filter Action Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionfilterattribute

I've tried this 2 different ways

This way works but processes all of the code for the action before performing the redirect.  This causes an issue where ever we are using the anti forgery token

```
    public class CheckAjaxRequestAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private const string AJAX_HEADER = "X-Requested-With";

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        bool isAjaxRequest = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers[AJAX_HEADER] != null;
        if (!isAjaxRequest)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/");
        }
    }
}
```

The second way I've seen recommend I receives the following error 
"Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions."

```
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Buffer = true;
        bool isAjaxRequest = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers[AJAX_HEADER] != null;
        string redirectUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}/", filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme, filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Authority);
        if (!isAjaxRequest)
        {
            //filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/");
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(redirectUrl);

        }
    }
}
```

The purpose of this is to prevent the partial views from loading when not being called via ajax.  The code works but the redirects errors and our security scan catches the issue when the `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` throws an error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add a tag for the programming language used in your code snippets (I assume it is C#).

Comment: The second way would work if you took off the `ChildActionOnly` attribute.

Comment: I'm not using the ChildActionOnly attribute

Answer (score 0):

For your isAjaxRequest, you should just be able to use:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have changed my code to use this but it does not resolve my issue.

Comment: Sorry, I would have put that in a comment rather than an answer, but I didn't have comment privileges yet. Anyway the way I've seen this done before is to use a custom ActionMethodSelectorAttribute ("CheckAjaxRequestAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute") and override the IsValidForRequest method to return false if it's not an Ajax request. Unfortunately, I think this will return a 404 if it's false and won't give you the redirect you want out of the box if you really need it to redirect to your default page.